# Splitting analog audio signal

Tags: amplifier, audio, pcb-design, analog

I have two areas of a PCB design where I would like to 'split' an analog audio signal to go to different input/output paths without affecting the signal characteristics.

The first situation is routing the differential output of an audio DAC to multiple output stages. One is a LPF circuit for lineout and the outher is a headphone amp.

The second situation is splitting a line in signal to an ADC and headphone amp circuit (for monitoring).

Any suggestions, circuit references or design considerations would be much appreciated.

Comment: A schematic, or even a block diagram, would greatly clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the input impedances of the two "sinks" (destinations) are high enough, and the output impedance of the source is low enough, there is little that you need to consider when splitting analog audio. If the input impedance is too low or your source is high impedance, add a buffer amplifier in between.

Of course, the regular common sense needed when routing noise-sensitive signals applies, but the signals are slow and the requirements of termination/stub management/signal integrity voodoo that are important in high-speed signal routing do not apply here.